# How do I disable the cache clear on comment form submission?

Tags: 7, hooks, caching

Unless I'm reading this incorrectly, it looks as if the last thing [comment_form_submit](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/function/comment_form_submit/7) does is clear the cache. All of it. This is done so anonymous users see the comment they posted.

I have a site that does, at times, receives high comment volume and the site does not allow anonymous users to post comments, so this behavior is suboptimal for me to say the least.

What's the Drupal way to override/kill the call to `cache_clear_all()` when comments are submitted? Can I do this in a module?

Comment: No fast and easy way to do it, you would have to write quite a bit of custom code.

Comment: Hmm.. How not fast and not easy? Could I just implement mymodule_comment_form_submit, copy and paste everything from comment_form_submit except for the final, cache-busting line?

Comment: Nope, you would also need to use hook_form_alter to switch submit functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be reasonably straight forward with a form alter (mileage may vary slightly here but this is the general idea):

```
function MYMODULE_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $key = array_search('comment_form_submit', $form['#submit']);
  if ($key !== FALSE) {
    $form['#submit'][$key] = 'MYMODULE_comment_form_submit';
  }
}

function MYMODULE_comment_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Copy code from comment_form() here, remove what you don't need.
}
```